# Can the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,dt-\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{3x^2}\right)$ be calculated?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, taylor-expansion

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,dt-\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{3x^2}\right)$$

I have this limit to be calculated. Since the first term takes the form $\frac 00$, I apply the L'Hospital rule. But after that all the terms are taking the form $\frac 10$. So, according to me the limit is $ ∞$. But in my book it is given 1/10. How should I solve it?

Comment: The limit of just the first term is infinity.  Are you getting something different when you use l'Hôpital on the first term?  If the answer is truly $1/10$ then these three terms need to work together to make it happen since each one by itself has an infinite limit.

Comment: @Debarun Mukherjee Just use L'hospital's rule. For the numerator use Leibnitz rule. After applying L'hospital 3times you will get something like e^x/10 now put x=0 and here's the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One may recall that, as $t \to 0$, by the Taylor series expansion
$$
e^{-t^2}=1-t^2+\frac{t^4}2+O(t^6)
$$ giving, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}{10}+O(x^7)
$$ and, as $x \to 0$,

> $$
> \frac1{x^5}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt-\frac1{x^4}+\frac1{3x^2}=\frac1{10}+O(x^2)
> $$

from which one deduces the desired limit.

Comment: Posted after my hint  I see ...

Answer (score 4):

By bringing the fractions to the same denominator, start by writing the limit as 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,dt -3x+x^3 }{3x^5}$$

Now, since this is of the form $0/0$ by L'H and FTC you get
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3e^{-x^2}-3+x^2 }{15x^4}$$

From here it is easy.

Comment: Doesn't this answer imply the limit is $\infty$? I don't see where the $1/10$th comes from here.

Comment: @AOrtiz Why infinity? This limit is $\frac{3-3}{0}$ which is still undetermined ;)

Comment: So what is actually happening? Is the limit $1/10$, or is it undetermined? Your answer claims the rest is easy, but the OP suggests the answer is something yours is not.

Comment: @AOrtiz Undetermined/Indefinite means you have to do more computations. Since it is of the form $0/0$ you can use L'H again. And since the denominator is $x^4$ you need to use L'H most likely 4 more times.

Comment: @N. S. yes I get it. My mistake was that I applied the L'H rule on the left most term without first simplifying the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $e^{-u} = 1-u+u^2/2 + O(u^3).$

Comment: @SujanDutta You should point that out to the OP.

Comment: I do not like L'Hopital in general, because it tends to be a mechanincal computation that doesn't yield much insight. (Although LHR does have its uses.) Using the hint gives a quicker proof and it also shows where the problem came from.